# Connecting mobile and PC to the same web server

Tags: mobile, webserver

Is it a proper design to have the same webserver to server both mobile clients as well as PCs. The main application will run on mobile which will login using web server and send and receive instructions and status to web server. PC log in is for allowing users to do their account administration purpose.

Will there be any issues in using a native non browser client (Android) talking to a web server?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's fine. In fact, for most sites you don't have to do anything at all to serve mobile clients. The browsers on most smart phones often use the same rendering engines as their desktop counterparts.

If you want to create a specific mobile experience, then that is best accomplished with mobile-specific stylesheets and possibly some mobile-specific javascript to tune some of the user interaction.

With regard to the design aspect, [Mobile Web Development](http://oreilly.com/iphone/excerpts/iphone-mobile-design-development/mobile-web-development.html) is a pretty good read.